# How can I do a loop within a "boolean conditional statement"?

Tags: c#, loops, conditional-statements

How can you put a loop within a conditional statement in C#? I have an example below where this could be useful in querying data for two reasons: it would avoid writing each item out or foreaching around the whole query, and it would avoid accessing the database for each item in the list if we assume the query is querying the database and we want to avoid the added hits to the database. So how can I loop within a conditional statement, like an if statement or a query statement. My take is that it would be pretty easy in a dynamic language like Ruby, but there's no easy way in C# or most static languages. Please let me know if I'm missing anything. Thanks.

```
List<string> certainTerritorysManagers = GetTerritoryManagers(east);
var AllSales= GetAllSales();
var EastTerritorySales =     (from sale in AllSales
             where sale.manager == manager1 || sale.manager == manager2 || ... etc.
             // *** Is there a way I can stick a foreach loop in the line above so I don't have to list all of these managers?
             // *** Pseudo code might look like: where sale.manager == ANYOF foreach (string manager in aCertainTerritoriesManagers)
             // *** If it was all && statements intead of || statements you could use the term ALLOF
             select sale).ToList();
```

Comment: Side note: actual answer *may* be different whether you have LINQ-to-Object or LINQ-to-SQL as not every type of query can be converted to SQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var EastTerritorySales = 
       (from sale in AllSales 
        where certainTerritoryManagers.Contains(sale.manager) 
        select sale).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there an equivalent to Contains() for an "&&" statement. And can this be used in a simple "if" statement? Like: `if (certainTerritoryManagers.Contains(sale.manager)){};` Thanks.

Comment: @EricMartin: By "an equivalent to contains for &&" do you mean where the item you're comparing is equal to *all* items in the list? Also, yes, the syntax you posted for an `if` statement is completely valid (except for the semicolon at the end, that is not necessary.

Comment: Ok, great. Thanks. That's what I meant, but now that you put it that way I see that it wouldn't be very useful.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like:

```
var eastTerritorySales =
(from sale in AllSales
where certainTerritorysManagers.Contains(sale.manager)
select sale).ToList();
```

Given that certainTerritorysManagers is a list of strings, the **sale.manager** need to be a string.
So, if the manager is another class with properties, you will need to do something like:

```
where certainTerritorysManagers.Contains(sale.manager.Name)
```

I hope it helps!